# Рендеринг html страницы в видео?

Tags: google-chrome

Как я могу рендерить html разметку в видео или секвенцию png, с прозрачным фоном, подобно тому как это делает программа OBS? Хром хедлесс поззволяет делать скриншоты в png но один скриншот занимает 100 миллисекунд, а это неприремлемо много.

Comment: Запустить хром с дисплеем и захватить видео с окна?

Comment: но ведь это не даст прозрачный фон, это даст белый фон(

Comment: В браузер.ксс белый фон замени на фиолетовый и выдели как хромокей

Comment: не, к сожалению это колхоз, это не позволит использовать фиолетовые цвета, а так же снимки скриншота занимают по 150 миллисекунд.

Comment: всё, нашел решение, электрон)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать Электрон, у окна есть метод `capturePage`

```
var image = await electronWindow.capturePage()
var frame = image.toPNG()
```

Фон получается прозрачный, и снимки занимают 50 миллисекунд